# Native c++ 3d math/geometry library for android?

Tags: android, c++, math, 3d

Does anyone know a c++ 3d math/geometry library that can be used on Android. Beside matrix calculations it should also support intersection tests like AABB.

So far I came across CML, but it doesnt support intersection tests. Beside that I'm not sure if CML works on Android since it isnt mentioned on the website.

Answer (score 2):

The [Computational Geometry Algorithms Library](http://www.cgal.org/) has the basic linear algebra stuff and some pretty advanced algorithms, including AABB. It claims support for GCC 3.4 and up. I haven't compiled the library on the Android NDK myself, but I expect you'll have no trouble building it using the gcc-arm compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You could borrow the maths code from the open source 3D engine Ogre. It's well written and mature, and released under the MIT license, so you can do what you like with it, more or less.

Comment: I just had a look at the code and noticed that Ogre is using STL, but Android only supports a limited set of STL.

Comment: Ogre in general does use the stl, but not much in the generic maths / AABB code (apart from ostream inserters, I think, which you could comment out). btw if you haven;t found it already, you can browse the source on bitbucket - https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/2f4baa3541e9/OgreMain/include/

Comment: @Rob
thanks for the information! it took me a while, but I finally managed to compile Ogre's math classes for Android. By the way, I found out that STLport is already included in the Android NDK, but is by default not compiled. So I added the line "APP_STL := stlport_static" to Application.mk.

Answer (score -3):

Android surport OpenGL ES for all developers. You should use JNI to build 3D project on Android. Use ndk-build to build 3D project.you can find some useful example by google android ndk. I used ndk little, but I believe that you use ndk to build 3D project is a good way.

Comment: I'm using OpenGL ES already for rendering. Since I am processing 3d data in real time I am looking for a math/geometry library to do matrix calculations and intersection tests.

Comment: And this is an answer to his question, because ...?